# Reset Smart Card pin having Muscle card applet

Tags: security, smartcard, javacard

I have GemsafeXpresso 64K-FIPS smart card. I managed to load a Muscle card applet and all the musclecard functions are working finely.
My question is if any user forgets his/her pin then how do I reset/change it.
I have gone through MscChangePin but it requires knowledge of old pin which a user now doesn't have.
I couldn't find any documentation on how to reset pin.
Please help me figure out how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSCUnblockPIN](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/libmusclecard/1.3.3/musclecard_8h.html#a563030a485c66017c66d44f42842b5e4) is the function to use, but you have to know the unblock value of course. The corresponding ISO command **Reset Retry Counter** allows variants without unblock value, but these need another kind of protection to avoid arbitrary many retries.

Comment: what i come to know from (http://www.linuxnet.com/musclecard/files/mcardprot-1.2.1.pdf) is MSCUnblockPin will unblock blocked pin. but it wont revel what exactly is the pin. I have already tried that. It unblocks the pin but what next now also user dont know the pin. with MSCUnblockPin, only he will get few more attempts to try but not the pin.

Comment: No card worth its money will ever echo the stored PIN value. The only choice you have is to establish a new value; this can be done using Reset Retry Counter command, too.

Comment: Ya i know no card will ever echo the pin but by that statement i meant it wont change the pin. Any way thank you Reset Retry Counter command seems to be helpful but ISO commands are not working with my card.